# Few questions about Song of Solomon

Tags: grammar, song-of-songs

> I have compared you, my love, To my filly among Pharaoh́s chariots
> (Song of Solomon 1:9)

Does it mean he was using chariots of Pharaoh or Pharaoh was using his horse?

King James Version says “a company of horses” without saying “my” before, so it seems the horses don't belong to the man:

> I have compared thee, O my love, to a company of horses in Pharaoh's
> chariots.

But that's not correct translation. The original hebrew text says ססתי (susati), which means “my company of horses”, not סוסה (susah), which means just “a company of horses” as it is in KJV

> Your head crowns you like Mount Carmel, And the hair of your head is
> like purple; A king (melech) is held captive by your tresses (Song of Solomon
> 7:5)

Why doesn't it say "the king", ha-melech like here:

> "The king (ha-melech) has brought me into his chambers" (1:4)

> Because of the fragrance of your good ointments, Your name is ointment
> (שמן shemen) poured forth (תורק turaq); Therefore the virgins love you
> (Song of Solomon 1:3)

According to [BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/songs/1-3.htm), תורק (turaq) is a feminine verb while שמן (shemen) is a masculine noun. Why is it like that? Shouldn't they have same gender?

Answer (score 0):

On your first question regarding **לְסֻסָתִי֙**:
Modern translations seem to be agreed that we are dealing with a singular horse, thus rejecting the Authorised version and the Vulgate. However, there is no such consensus on whether it is "my" mare or "a" mare with the NIV and the ESV both saying "a". what appears to be happening is that the age and poetic form of the book makes it a little ambiguous what is the case. The translators then look at the *context* and since the speaker having a horse in Pharaoh's chariots does not make sense then "a mare" is used instead.

On your second regarding the difference between **הַמֶּ֜לֶךְ** and **מֶּ֜לֶךְ**:

The reason for the difference is because הַמֶּ֜לֶךְ (the king) is referring to a particular king - Solomon. It is narrative - whether or not it actually occurred - of the Woman being taken by the King into his chambers.

In 7:5 in contrast we have a trio of descriptions that compliment the hair of the Woman. We have a hypothetical king who if he were to see her tresses would be captivated (on account of them crowning her head like Mt. Carmel and being like purple threads.)

I answer your third question here: [Grammar question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/90722/grammar-question/91249#91249)

References:
https://biblehub.com/songs/1-9.htm
https://biblehub.com/commentaries/songs/1-9.htm